# Twitter4j cannot redirect back to app after login

Tags: android, twitter, access-token

I'm using twitter4j to get user token and secret.
I have a problem when twitter should redirect back to my app after the login. The browser stay in foreground and the activity is never resumed.

Here is the activity declaration in the manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".TwitterActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="myapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I have declared these constants:

```
private static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "myapp:///";
private static final String TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER_URL = "oauth_verifier";
```

When the user click on the login button:

```
ConfigurationBuilder configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    configBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_key));
    configBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_secret));
    mTwitter = new TwitterFactory(configBuilder.build()).getInstance();
    mProgressDialog.show();
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                mTwitterRequestToken = mTwitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(mTwitterRequestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
        }
    }.execute();
```

In the `onResume` method, I check for the intent and retrieve the token and the secret

```
Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
    if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
        String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER_URL);
        try {
            mTwitterToken = mTwitter.getOAuthAccessToken(mTwitterRequestToken, verifier);
            Toast.makeText(this, "token: " + mTwitterToken.getToken() + "\nSecret: " + mTwitterToken.getTokenSecret(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try handle your callbacks in `onCreate()` instead of `onResume()`.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="callback"
                android:scheme="x-oauthflow-twitter" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>

String OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME = "x-oauthflow-twitter";
String OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST = "callback";
String callBack = OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME+ "://" + OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST;
twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(callBack);
```

Now override onNewIntent method

```
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = activity.getSharedPreferences(Common.TAG,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String callBackScheme = OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME;
        final Uri uri = intent.getData();
        if (uri != null && uri.getScheme().equals(callBackScheme)) {
            new RetrieveAccessTokenTask(prefs).execute(uri);
        }
    }
```